Correct way to access database when working with multiple JS files
JavaScript and PostgreSQL.
class User {
  constructor(username, password, company_id, acclevel) {
    this.username = username;
    this.company_id = company_id;
    this.acclevel = acclevel;
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
    this.hash = crypto
      .pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, "sha512")
      .toString("hex");
  }

This is in my user.js file. The main file is my index.js. Is it best practice to keep my database manipulations inside ONLY index.js or is it plausible to have the database manipulation happen within ANY .js file that requires it.
What I am trying to do is store the User information in a database (ik how to do this) but am unsure of how to create a function inside this User class that can interact with the database in my index.js file, without opening the database in user.js. The main concern is password verification functionality inside of User class, as that requires it to open/pull from the database of users to get the hash/salt of the user.
The brute force way, not using OOP, swapping to OOP for cleaner code.
app.post("/createcompany", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("got /createcompany");
  const access_code = req.body.access_code;
  const userName = req.body.userName;
  const inputPW = req.body.passW;
  const package_Purchased = req.body.package;
  if (access_code == main_Access_Code) {
    console.log("Authorized Account Creation in progress");
    try {
      await db.query("INSERT INTO users (username, package) VALUES ($1, $2)", [
        userName,
        package_Purchased,
      ]);
      try {
        var salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
        var hashedPW = crypto.pbkdf2(
          inputPW,
          salt,
          1000,
          64,
          "sha512",
          async (err, derivedKey) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            } else {
              let hash = derivedKey.toString("hex");
              await db.query(
                "UPDATE users SET usersalt = $1, userhash = $2 WHERE username = $3",
                [salt, hash, userName]
              );
              console.log(salt, derivedKey.toString("hex"), userName);
            }
          }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      }
      try {
        const company_uuid = await db.query(
          "SELECT company_id FROM users WHERE $1 = username",
          [userName]
        );
        res.redirect(`/${company_uuid.rows[0].company_id}`);
        console.log(`got /${company_uuid.rows[0].company_id}`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("wtf", err);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Sorry that username already exists");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("incorrect access code");
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});

Verification brute force way
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("got /login");
  const userName = req.body.userName;
  const passW = req.body.passW;
  try {
    const result = await db.query(
      "SELECT username, usersalt, userhash, company_id FROM users WHERE $1 = username",
      [userName]
    );
    try {
      let usersalt = result.rows[0].usersalt;
      let test = crypto.pbkdf2(
        passW,
        usersalt,
        1000,
        64,
        "sha512",
        async (err, derivedKey) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          } else {
            let key = derivedKey.toString("hex");
            if (key === result.rows[0].userhash) {
              console.log("SUCCESS!!!");
              res.redirect(`/${result.rows[0].company_id}`);
            } else {
              console.log("login attempt unsuccessful");
              res.redirect("/login");
            }
          }
        }
      );
    } catch {}
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  }
});



For anyone viewing this, after a bit of research and viewing other projects, I have found that is normal practice to have SQL queries anywhere they are required, in any file. Just ensure that the queries only access what they need to access, and are not pulling additional information from the DB that is not required as this will lead to security issues (backdoors) and slow down the computing time of your application/program!
